# Mongo distinct query with sort not working

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, distinct-values

I'm running a query in mongo using php like this:

```php
$column ='address.roadname';



(new MongoDB\Client())->db->mycollection->distinct($column,[],['$sort'=> [$column => 1]]);
```

The query gives results, but those are not sorted.
What am I missing?

The data are just strings "nested" into inner object
What I expect is a list of street names sorted alphabetically

sample data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "tizio",
    "address": [
      {
        "roadType": "via",
        "roadname": "Roma",
        "number": "12 bis",
        "city": "Milano"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "via",
        "roadname": "Emilia",
        "number": "124",
        "city": "Modena"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "via",
        "roadname": "Appia",
        "number": "89",
        "city": "Genova"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "caio",
    "address": [
      {
        "roadType": "vicolo",
        "roadname": "stretto",
        "number": "12",
        "town": "Monza"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "largo",
        "roadname": "Garibaldi",
        "number": "24",
        "city": "Modena"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "piazza",
        "roadname": "Armi",
        "number": "26",
        "city": "Rovigo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "sempronio",
    "address": [
      {
        "roadname": "Roma",
        "number": "15",
        "city": "Milano"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "via",
        "roadname": "Po",
        "number": "4",
        "city": "Torino"
      },
      {
        "roadType": "largo",
        "roadname": "Garibaldi",
        "number": "9",
        "community": "Genova"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what I expect:

```
Appia,Armi,Emilia,Garibaldi,Po,Roma,Stretto
```

note: if I run it on mongo console

```js
db.mycollection.distinct("address.roadname").sort()
```

I got the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP implementation of distinct does have a `sort` option, see https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.7/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-distinct/

In your shell example,

```
db.mycollection.distinct("address.roadname")
```

returns an array, so when you run `.sort()` on that it is using the javascript [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

The PHP distinct function also returns an array, so use the [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function on it.